# Date conversion issue in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have an issue of converting time into 24 hours from 12 hours. For this I did all the required things and followed mostly all the stack overflow answers but it didn't help me. What exactly I need to do is I have a `NSString` object having time (not date) in 12 hours like 6:00 pm and I need to change this in 24 hours (18:00). Here is what I did for this :

```
NSString* dateString = startTime;
NSDateFormatter* fmt = [NSDateFormatter new];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate* date = [fmt dateFromString:dateString];
```

But it returns me `nil` date. What can be missing here?

**Update :**

One more thing,12 hours time gives me correct result but 'am' and 'pm' are small letters so is there any procedure to have these in capital letters.

Comment: Your date format doesn't include the am/pm indicator, which is probably why it's failing to convert the string to a date.

Comment: We already have am/pm in start time (6:00 pm) and here in 24 hours format,why we should take am/pm?

Comment: @sam What does your date string look like?  Usually a problem with mismatch between date string and format string.

Comment: @dboals the format is h:mm a which is in 12 hours and we need to change this in 24 hours..

Comment: Right, but what does start time look like.  Can you give a real example.  h:mm is a format and you said am/pm is in the time string.   Is the string "12:00 pm GMT" or something like that?

Comment: Thanks  dboals for your response but Raymond Lee's answer is the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString* dateString = @"6:00 pm";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];
return [dateFormat stringFromDate: date];
```